# Bootstrap rawspan and column span

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Can anybody help me with this problem, I am using bootstrap to develop my website and so far I have two row`s.

```
   <section role="main">
       <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-space"><!-- Row 1 -->
            <div class="span3">             
                <h2>{ logo here }</h2>
                <h3>[ logo here ]</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="span6">
                <h2>Text here, text here <em>text here</em>...</h2>
                <h2>text here!</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="span3">
                <img src="img/coffee.png" alt="Coffee and code">
            </div>

        </div><!-- /Row 1 -->

        <div class="row no-space"><!-- Row 2 -->
            <div class="span3">
                <img src="img/code01.png" alt="Coda2 code">
            </div>                  
            <div class="span3">
                <img src="img/code01.png" alt="Coda2 code">
            </div>
        </div><!-- /Row 2-->
    </div><!-- Container -->
 </section><!-- MAIN -->
```

The entire website will be built using span3 and 6, with a height of 220 for span3 and 460 for span6. Because span6 has a double height as against span 3, it will be a gap of 240px between the span3 from the first row and the first span3 from the secound row.

How I can remove this gap, I tried nesting but is not really something that I need, because the divs(span3) will be shuffled every time the website will be reloaded.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what u want to do is think of the spans as columns and add the data inside of the columns

```
   <section role="main">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-space"><!-- Row 1 -->
        <div class="span3">             
            <h2>{ logo here }</h2>
            <h3>[ logo here ]</h3>
            <img src="img/code01.png" alt="Coda2 code">
        </div>

        <div class="span6" data-rowspan="2" data-colspan="2">
            <h2>Text here, text here <em>text here</em>...</h2>
            <h2>text here!</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="span3">
            <img src="img/coffee.png" alt="Coffee and code">
            <img src="img/code01.png" alt="Coda2 code">
        </div>

    </div><!-- /Row 1 -->
</div><!-- Container -->
```